# Permission denied error when using Github deploy keys

Tags: git, deployment, github, amazon-ec2, key

So I have a project (private repo) that has multiple submodules (also private). I have a server hosted on Amazon EC2 that will house the project, and I want to use our private Github repo.

I generated an ssh key for the main project and added it to the projects deploy keys. I also generated additional ssh keys for each submodule and added it to their deploy keys.

When I try and clone the project (using git@github), it doesn't work:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have double checked each repo and their deploy keys and everything seems correct. Is there some other small step I am missing?

Comment: Is the port 22 opened? What does `ssh -vT git@github.com` say? - http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Comment: OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0i-fips 19 Apr 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: there is no easy way to use deploy keys with private submodules.  In my experience you have two options:

1. Keep using submodules but stop using deploy keys and instead use a single account-level SSH key that grants access to all your private repositories (easier, less secure)
2. Stop using submodules, keep using deploy keys, and manually `git clone` each repository passing in the SSH private key that matches the deploy key (trickier, more secure)

The reason for this is `git clone` triggers an SSH connection that can only use *a single SSH private key at a time* (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa).  The SSH private key being used must match the repository's deploy key -- and deploy keys must be unique per project.  In the case of a submodule clone, you're only using a single private key.  That key may match your top-level project, but will surely fail on the child projects with the error you provided.

Hope this is helpful..

Comment: As of 2 years later there is still no better solution?

Comment: OK, found it: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth

Comment: @aledalgrande not really a solution, though. It forces me to use tokens instead of ssh keys.

Comment: @aledalgrande 2020 and this is still an issue actually

Comment: Still in 2023...